# Javascript onClick event in all cells

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript and I've not that much experience.
But I'm making a HTML table and I want to add in every table cell (`<td>`) a onClick event.

```
<table id="1">
    <tr>
        <td onClick="tes()">1</td><td onClick="tes()">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onClick="tes()">3</td><td onClick="tes()">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there another way to do this event in every cell?

Comment: you'll be amazed when you learn [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) it will help you a lot

Comment: At first learn vanilla `JS` then go for `jQuery`.

Comment: with html5, use jQuery. its easy and helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

```
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
   cells[i].onclick = function(){tes();};
}
```

and the other way using jQuery:

```
$('td').click(function(){tes();});
```

**upd:**

To get exactly what is needed, firstly the table must be selected, so, for the first option:

```
var table = document.getElementById('1');
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
...
```

and for the second, the jQ selector should be like this:

```
$('#1 td')
```

Comment: using td as the selector would mean that any table that has a td will have a click event.  I would suggest be more specific

Comment: @Johan, thanks! This answer was given just for the table included in the question :)

Comment: Although this may work, for the table in the question, if the user has another table on the same page, this will add events to that table as well, which makes this answer wrong (unless the OP wants it for ALL tables)

Answer (score 17):

I know this is a bit old, but you should use a click envent on the table and use the target value to get the cell. Instead of having a 10 x 10 table = 100 event you will have only 1.

The best thing with that method is when you add new cells you don't need to bind an event again.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myTable').click( function(event) {
      var target = $(event.target);
      $td = target.closest('td');
      
      $td.html(parseInt($td.html())+1);
      var col   = $td.index();
      var row   = $td.closest('tr').index();

      $('#debug').prepend('<div class="debugLine">Cell at position (' + [col,row].join(',') + ') clicked!</div>' );
      
    });
  });
```

```css
td {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

#debug {
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

#debug .debugLine {
    margin: 2px 0;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    background-color: #EEE;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>    
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>    
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>    
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: I think for larger tables this has huge performance implications vs just tagging each element with the same function. This is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks. this works well. My IE6 was hanging because i was adding event for every cell. Moving it to one event per table, solved the issue

Comment: Thank you, your answer is appreciated a couple years later.

Answer (score 7):

You may try this too (using event delegation)

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('tbl1').onclick = function(e){
        var e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if(target.tagName.toLowerCase() ==  "td") {
            alert(target.innerHTML);
        }
    };
};
```

[EXAMPLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/ArNJA/)

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

```
$(function(){
    $('#tbl1').on('click', 'td', function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

[EXAMPLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/ArNJA/2/)

Comment: This is the better answer here, everyone else is suggesting just using the td and that isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just the following code will return the contained text of the clicked element. In this case the td

```
event.target.innerText
```

**Example:**

```css
td
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
     <table onclick="alert(event.target.innerText)">
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 3</td>
            <td>cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Of course you can implement it into a js and attach it to the onclick event as usual (search for the **addEventListener()** function in javascript).
If needed you can separate the table into thead, tbody tfoot and add the onclick event to the tbody only. In this way the event will be triggered only if the user clicks on this section of the table and not when he clicks on other elements...

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var i in tds) tds[i].onclick = tes;
```

and a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wWGge/)...

---

Replace **document** with any other dom element that you need to find td's in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
  var tbl = document.getElementById("1");
    var numRows = tbl.rows.length;

    for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
        var ID = tbl.rows[i].id;
        var cells = tbl.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        for (var ic=0,it=cells.length;ic<it;ic++) {
            cells[ic].OnClick = new function() {tes()};
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to jquery, do this

```
$('#1 td').click(function(){

});
```

Comment: Jquery isn't tagged in question.

Answer (score 0):

You might not require putting `onclick` event on every `TD` element in your table. Providing `onclick`event at the table level can do the trick easily as shown in the below code snippet:

```js
function tes(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName == "TD") {
    alert('TD got clicked');
  }
}
```

```css
  
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <table id='gameBoard' width="300" height="300" onclick="tes(event);">
        <tr>
          <td data-index = "0 0"></td>
          <td data-index = "0 1"></td>
          <td data-index = "0 2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-index = "1 0"></td>
            <td data-index = "1 1"></td>
            <td data-index = "1 2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-index = "2 0"></td>
            <td data-index = "2 1"></td>
            <td data-index = "2 2"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can do the appropriate handling inside `tes` function with the help of `event` parameter.