# How to add click event to table cell in this code?

Tags: javascript

In this code, I want to make the table cell clickable with javascript.

Please also tell me how to use i,j values with the click event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 td 
 {
   height : 30px;
   width : 30px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
</style>

<script>
function clickHere(){
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row ;
var cell;
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
  row = table.insertRow(i);
  for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
    cell = row.insertCell(j);
  }
 }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="clickHere()">
 <table id = "myTable" border="1"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript onClick event in all cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155189/javascript-onclick-event-in-all-cells)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this code:

```
cell.addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("cell clicked");
});
```

After this code:

```
cell = row.insertCell(j);
```

It will add event listener to each cell. when clicked it will show an alert.

Answer (score 3):

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "TD") {
    alert('Cell clicked')
  }
});
```

Comment: This would be perfect to get me started, but unfortunately it is not working. The brackets are not closed correctly. This needs tidying up. The second last curly bracket should be removed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After the cell is added to the DOM you can add eventListeners to it. 
So the only thing you have to do, is add the eventListener :)

```
// here you add the cell and have a reference to it
cell = row.insertCell(j);

// now you can add eventlisteners to it
cell.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('cell clicked');
});
```

About adding event listeners: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kt9g8h4w/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener first and write a function with same listener name which will be executed after clicked. Try the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

td {
height : 30px;
width : 30px;
cursor: pointer;
}


</style>
<script>

function clickHere(){

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row ;
var cell;
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
      row = table.insertRow(i);
      row.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerRow);
      for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
            cell = row.insertCell(j);
            cell.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerColumn);
        }
    }
}

function clickHandlerRow(e) {
    alert("row clicked");
}

function clickHandlerColumn(e) {
    alert("column clicked");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="clickHere()">

<table id = "myTable" border="1"></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

$("#myInput").val($(This).children().eq(0).text());
- above code
(1) 'myInput' is id of input box where we display the selected table cell value.
(2)'eq(0)'-> which  denote ,cell position value display in required in input box.

Comment: You probably can improve clarity of your answer by using markdown formattign options. Take the [tour] to learn more about how things are done on StackOverflow.