# Make each specific cell clickable in a HTML table in php

Tags: javascript, html-table, cell

I have a HTML table looking like the following:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm res-table" id="reservationtable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z"/></svg></th>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l") . "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y"); ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+1 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+1 day")); ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+2 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+2 day")); ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+3 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+3 day")); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Zeit</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">08:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">09:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

What I want to do is open a bootstrap modal when a cell is clicked, which can then be used to populate the cell. But for that I need to get the specific cell which is clicked somehow. I haven't found anything specific online, hopefully you can help me.

Cheers,
Zangerle

Comment: the `event` property for the `click` event will give access to the cell that was clicked using `event.target`

Comment: in this case you need to give a unique id to every cell like cell1, cell2, cell3.....etc. After that use a hyperlink or button with related tax and add you function, then cache the data from reference ID you given to cell.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius It seems to work, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad I was able to offer some assistance. Good luck with the remaining coding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript onClick event in all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155189/javascript-onclick-event-in-all-cells)

Comment: The possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155189/javascript-onclick-event-in-all-cells/19155248 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589777/how-to-add-click-event-to-table-cell-in-this-code and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript below will trigger some basic actions when a table cell is clicked - how that click event is handled is up to you but you would use the callback to run whatever routines you wish

```js
const clickcallback=function(e){
    e.target.style.background='red';
    // alternatively you can use `this` to access the element in this instance
    alert(this)
}

document.querySelectorAll('table#reservationtable td').forEach( td=>{
    td.addEventListener('click',clickcallback)
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm res-table" id="reservationtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z"/></svg></th>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l") . "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y"); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+1 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+1 day")); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+2 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+2 day")); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+3 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+3 day")); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Zeit</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
            <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">08:00</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">09:00</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```