# why link is not working outside <td> html

Tags: hyperlink, html-table

I want code in which when I click on the whole part of `<td>` (including the `td` background image) the link will open. I am trying that code but when I click on whole part of `<td>` then nothing happens. I am able to open link when I click on the link only, so what to do.

Here is the code

```html
<td width="47%" height="150">
    <a href="MY_LINK">
        <div width="47"  class="gimg">
            <style type="text/css">

.gimg {
    background-image: url("IMAGE_LINK");
    background-color: lightblue;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
            </style>
            </br/>
            <font color="#ECEFF1"><b>LINK_NAME</b></font>
        </div>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: What is that part that works on clicking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript onClick event in all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155189/javascript-onclick-event-in-all-cells)

Comment: @GSerg How is this related to the onClick event?

Comment: @AakashVerma Your [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881727/why-link-is-not-working-outside-td-html?noredirect=1#comment82729248_47881727) makes it look like you did not read the question, your [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881727/why-link-is-not-working-outside-td-html#comment82729338_47881727) makes that impression stronger. Are there better ways of performing an action when the user clicks white space inside a `td`?

Comment: @GSerg Instead of making the `td` clickable, he can go for a clickable image with src attribute (instead of going for div) which spans the entire `td`... where is that onClick event handling again?

Comment: @AakashVerma with src attribute the text and image gets separated.. i want text inside the image and link is also working for both